# How to update the App Engine Application Name when using Google Account UserService

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have an existing App Engine (Java) app and we use the [UserService](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/users/UserService) for Google Account authentication of our users.

We'd like to update the Application name that shows up on this screen when users click through to allow access to their Google Account:
[image]

I am pretty sure it was an option in the *old* App Engine console/settings screen but I cannot find it in the new settings screen.

Does anyone know where this setting has been moved to or how to update the Application name?

As an aside, incase any App Engine team members track this tag, is App Engine OK? Is anyone testing it? I am a bit nervous! This is how my settings screen looks in the new Cloud Console:

[image]

Comment: I found a very old tutorial (2012) here that shows the screen where the App's name is set on creation (http://www.sitepoint.com/google-app-engine-gae-java-api-part-3-getting-started-with-apis/) - is it possible this can only be set once when the app is created?

Comment: I've opened [an issue](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12919) with the AppEngine team. It references both this StackOverflow question and [my own](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36803096)

Comment: @klenwell thanks, that's great - hoping we can get this sorted!

Comment: The defect was acknowledged by a [Google engineer](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1543502/e-anderson) in  [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36920717/1093087). @steeling suggests a workaround in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36829844/1093087) that worked for me.

Comment: Thanks klenwell and @steeling - this worked great! (@steeling - is App Engine OK? I'm nervous about how buggy the transition to cloud.google.com has been, it makes me worried GAE is being left to wither)

Answer (score 0):

From the [Signing in and out](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/users/#Java_Signing_in_and_out) section of the Users Java API Overview doc:

> If your app uses Google Accounts or Google Apps for authentication,
>   the name of your application appears on the sign-in page when the user
>   signs in to your application, using the application name you chose
>   when registering the application. You can change your application name
>   in the Google Cloud Platform Console [projects page](https://console.cloud.google.com//project). Click on the
>   pencil icon for the project you want to rename.

Comment: that doesn't seem to be the right place, I know there is an OAuth feature in App Engine, but this is specifically using the Google Accounts for the App Engine internal OAuth. The page URL starts with https://appengine.google.com/_ah/loginform?state=[...snip...]

Comment: I had found that screen already, but the name there doesn't match what is being displayed to the users. I'll try and update it anyway, maybe something got lost in the migration to the new cloud console and it needs to be re-saved.

Comment: I tried it 5 minutes and 2 hours after updating and results are the same, that project name is *not* the same name being displayed on that login page.

Comment: FWIW, you're not the only one seeing this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36803096/with-google-app-engine-is-it-possible-to-customize-boilerplate-in-default-user.

Answer (score 0):

Confirming the answer from @steeling in this python Q works:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36829844/883778

Not sure if there's a *proper* way to refer to another question's answer as the answer for this question. If there is let me know.