# With Google App Engine, is it possible to customize boilerplate in default user authorization template?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-signin

I'm referring to the page at https://appengine.google.com/_ah/loginform that the user will be redirected to by the `users.create_login_url` method from the `google.appengine.api` module. This is for [authentication using Google Accounts](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/).

I'd like to change references to the project name (which is different from my custom domain) to match my domain.

The page currently says:

> The application **project-name** is requesting permission to access your Google Account.

I'd prefer it said:

> The application **example.com** is requesting permission to access your Google Account.

I've updated the settings in the Google Cloud Platform dashboard under **API Manager > Credentials > OAuth Consent Screen**, but (even a couple hours later) that doesn't seem to have had any impact.

I've searched the App Engine settings in the dashboard as well. Is this possible? If not, suggestions for a workaround?

#### Update

I've opened up an issue ([Issue 12919](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12919)) on Google Code as suggested by @DanCornilescu below. It references both this question and [the other recent StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36682561/) related to this issue.

I also raised the issue on Reddit in the [AppEngine subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AppEngine/). The Google dev marked the Google Code ticket private so I could upload some private project information, but I'll update its status in the [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/AppEngine/comments/4g93oh/how_can_i_change_the_project_name_in_signin_page/).

#### Workaround

[@steeling's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36829844/1093087) below offers a workaround that worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bug here, but in the meantime you can go through the old admin console at [appengine.google.com](http://appengine.google.com). If you click "Application Settings" after clicking on your application it will take you to the new cloud console. But if you right click and copy the link and remove the "&deprecated" at the end of the url you can still visit the old page.

Comment: You'll need to clarify the `your_project > settings` step. I don't see a settings option. I did change change the name according to the documentation and see it reflected in the dashboard but not the sign-in page.

Comment: Sorry about that! Final edit should get it to work now :)

Comment: Thanks. That worked for me. If this works for Java users, too, you may want to post an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36682561/1093087).

Answer (score 2):

There's currently a bug where changes to the project title are not getting synced to App Engine *after* you create the application.

This is definitely a bug, and we're working on figuring out what broke this sync.

Comment: Thanks for the acknowledgement. I'll continue to follow the progress of [Issue 12919](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12919).